# OpenCV Face Detection and Face Recognition

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to implement Face Recognition using OpenCV. I have successfully used Haar Transformations to detect a face in a picture. However I am somehow puzzled by the fact that the Face Recognition requires images of same dimensions in order to be trained.

```
    Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer(0,Threshold);
    Mat m0 = imread(".\\1.jpg",0);
    Mat m1 = imread(".\\2.jpg",0);
    Mat m2 = imread(".\\3.jpg",0);
    vector<int> labels = {1,2,3};
    vector<Mat> m = {m0,m1,m2};
    model->train(m,labels); // This throws if the images are not the same size
```

How am I supposed to implement it properly then? Should I enlarge all my images to the dimensions that the largest image has? But in that case, do I fill with "transparent" color the rest of the image if it is smaller than the max dimensions image?

Best Regards.

Comment: Perhaps you could add and image or two to make it clear what the issue is with resizing

Comment: I don't know if there is an issue in resizing. I am just asking the proper way to resize the images.

Comment: yes you will have to resize all images to the same size. choose something small, like 100x100. same for the test-images later. also, `resize(src,dst,Size(100,100));`